# Artin's proof of the generalized associative law

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand Artin's proof of the generalized associative law. I've included a screenshot below.

[image]

Here are the questions I have on his proof:

1. I am not completely sure what his base cases establish: they're part of the given definition. I assume what he means is that the proposition is 'we can define a unique product of $n$ elements for any $n$' and it's obvious that we can do that when $n=1$ (just the element itself) and when $n=2$ (because the law of composition is a well-defined function).
2. The line "it does satisfy (iii) when $n=2$ confuses me because if $n=2$, I can only write $(a_1 a_2)$ without any kind of parentheses or any choice of $I$. The only thing I can say for certain is that (iii) definitely holds when $n=3$ because of the associative law.
3. I assume when he assumes the product is defined for a product of $r$ elements where $r \leq n-1$, he is assuming that $n \geq 2$ because the base case covered through $n=2$. Is this right?
4. In the inductive step, I don't understand why he is allowed to "define" the product of $n$ elements. By the inductive hypothesis, $[a_1 \cdots a_{n-1}]$ and $[a_n]$ are already defined, but I'm trying to prove that the product of $n$ elements is well-defined, i.e., that the notation $[a_1 \cdots a_n]$ is valid. Why is he allowed to define it in this way?
5. I do n't understand his point on uniqueness: "if a product satisfying (iii) exists, then this formula gives the product because it is (iii) when $I=n-1$. So if it exists, the product is unique. I get that this is indeed (iii) with $I=n-1$ (though that seems artificial to me, still, because he defined it that way), but why does this imply uniqueness? Doesn't this require that every line of the equation chain generates a unique product?

Comment: (1) You assume right. (2) Exactly. (3) Yes. (4) He's essentially showing all parenthesizations are equivalent by showing they're all equivalent to the specific one $((\cdots(a_1)a_2\cdots)a_{n-1})a_n$. If we assume this is true for $r<n$, then all we need to do to show it for $r=n$ is work with $(i$ terms$)(n-i$ terms$)$ for each possible $i$. (5) Uniqueness for $n$ follows from uniqueness for $n-1$, so induction applies. Also, ironically, you forgot to close your quotation marks!

Comment: Is the idea for uniqueness that if the product satisfying (iii) exists, it's a product of two things we know exist and are unique, and we know that a product of two things exists, so it has to be unique by the original law of composition?

Comment: Any time you have an explicit formula for something involving well-defined operations, you're specifying something uniquely.